# Problems connecting to MongoDB-Atlas with Twisted Python 3.7

Tags: mongodb, python-3.7, twisted, atlas

I have an application running Twisted Python 3.7, and we're trying to convert it to run against Atlas and not our own managed MongoDB.

Our local MongoDB has no authentication so it was pretty straight forward. But moving to Atlas we now need to use TLS for the connection and I keep on getting **TxMongo lost connection to MongoDB.** after connecting.

My connection is of type **mongodb+srv://.../?authSource=%24external&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&retryWrites=true&w=majority** and I have the certificate and private key files, of course.

I tried using *txmongo* example from [their own example](https://txmongo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but it doesn't work for me.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Thanks,
Oren

Edit: 1/1/23:
I changed the example code a bit, changing the SSL example as follows:

**TxMongo original code**

```
class ServerTLSContext(ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory):
def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    kw['sslmethod'] = SSL.TLSv1_METHOD
    ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
```

**My change**

```
class ServerTLSContext(ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory):
def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    kw['sslmethod'] = SSL.TLSv1_2_METHOD  #    v1_METHOD
    ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
```

The only change is the SSL TSL method.
Now my errors are different. No more disconnections, but a warning in case the initial connection was not made to the master node:
*'TxMongo: MongoDB host `atlas-XXX-shard-00-02.XXX.mongodb.net:27017` is not master.'*

Once it is connected to the master, I get an error:
*TxMongo: not authorized for query on db.collection* (real db and connection name in the original error, of course)

So again - any ideas?

Comment: Try finding more details about why the connection is being closed.  Chances are there is more information _somewhere_ which will help you understand the problem in more detail and then find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

`pip install certifi`

```
import certifi
MongoClient(url_connection, tlsCAFile=certifi.where())
```

Comment: This seems like a PyMongo connection, not txmongo (for Twisted Python)...

Comment: I looked it up a bit more, and certifi doesn't let me use my own certificate and private files, which I need for this mongo connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Atlas then from the web console navigate to the db view and press 'connect' you can get a connection string which you can test with Compass or mongosh.  Also, remember to set the network access otherwise your connection will fail.
[image: atlas web console]

Comment: Thanks, but obviously I've done that. As I wrote, I already use this connection string with other microservices in the same deployment. Only the Twisted Python fails connecting,